# Replace several letters in math font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, sans-serif, sourcesanspro

I need to typeset a whole document sans serif with `sourcesanspro`, including formulas. I know that there are a lot of arguments against doing this, but in this particular case it makes sense.

My problem is (as often asked at several places of the web), that I don't find a proper sans serif math font. I searched the web for hours and tested a lot of possibilities (`arec`. `cmbright`, `iwona` ...) but ended up using `sansmath`.

As far as I understood `sansmath`, it uses the default sans serif family for typesetting formulas. The problem is, that `sourcesanspro` doesn't include greek letters or symbols like blackboard fonts.

Is it possible to replace several symbols of the math font, e. g. greek letters, by the greek letters of other fonts manually?

That's my MWE, so far:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath

\begin{document}


\noindent
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ \\
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \\
$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$ \\
$ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$ \\
$\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\varkappa\lambda\mu\nu\xi o\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi\chi\psi\omega$ \\
$\Gamma\Delta\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega$ \\
$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\[
  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma f = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k) \cdot \text{Res}(f;a_k).
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Sans serif document]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174386/detexify-couldnt-help-me-find-and-can-you/174429#174429

Comment: Thank you! Nice to be here! This site is a real enrichment for (La)TeX user!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This uses Iwona for Greek, change the font family in `\DeclareSymbolFont` if you want a different font.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath

\DeclareSymbolFont{Greekletters}{OT1}{iwona}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{greekletters}{OML}{iwona}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathord}{Greekletters}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathord}{Greekletters}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathord}{Greekletters}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathord}{Greekletters}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathord}{Greekletters}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathord}{Greekletters}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathord}{Greekletters}{"07}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathord}{Greekletters}{"08}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathord}{Greekletters}{"09}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathord}{Greekletters}{"0A}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"27}


\begin{document}


\noindent
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ \\
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \\
$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$ \\
$ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$ \\
$a\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\varkappa\lambda\mu\nu\xi o\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi\chi\psi\omega$ \\
$\Gamma\Delta\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega$ \\
$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\[
  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma f = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k) \cdot \text{Res}(f;a_k).
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

***Personal opinion*** Sans serif math can be justified only in a presentation.

Comment: That's exactly what I looked for, thank you very much!

Just to be clear:

Comment: Just to be clear: `\DeclareSymbolFont{Greekletters}{OT1}{iwona}{m}{n}` declares the new symbol font `Greekletters` using `iwona` and `\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathord}{Greekletters}{"01}` (re)declares the command `\Delta` to be typeset in `Greekletters` font?

One more question: Where do I find the numbers, e. g. `"01` for the large delta?

**Personal answer** I totally agree with you! I create a document class (my first, by the way) for overhead transparencies I want to use at school.

Comment: The numbers are the standard ones for OT1 (uppercase Greek) and OML (lowercase Greek) encoded fonts; you find them in `fontmath.ltx`. Note that I changed the default `\mathalpha` for the uppercase Greek into `\mathord` or the letters would respect the `\sansmath` declaration.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much! Fonts are a really big topic (despite or maybe because of the many information in the web), so it is really helpful to get some support here. :o)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with numbers. Just add 
```1234567890\\
$1234567890$\\```
to the example and you'll see. Any tip to solve it?

Comment: @LEo There is a 2 in the example formula and it is sans serif.

Comment: @egreg not inline... just add the 1234... as you added the abcd... and you will see.

Comment: @LEo Sorry, but if I add ``1234567890\\$1234567890$`` just after `\noindent`, I get the expected result: the digits print the same and sans serif.

Comment: @egreg here is the result I get: https://i.imgur.com/89SMiqy.png  In fact,

Comment: @LEo Sorry, but it's not what I get *from the example*. You might have something different in your document.

Comment: @egreg it was a problem with Texmaker built-in viewer