# Replace a few math symbols in the newtxmath font

Tags: fonts, math-mode, newtxmath

I use the `\newtxmath` as the math font in my document and `\newtxtext` for the text. This seems to work fine, but I need to replace some math symbols which seem to me not as nice as their default Latin Modern Math counterpart. The symbols I need to replace, e.g., are:

- `\int` and `\sum`: they look so high and big,
- `\infty`: looks too small, and
- `\partial` and `\pi`: looks strange too.

I have searched for similar or near question like this one ([Replace several letters in math font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195832/replace-several-letters-in-math-font)), but I haven't been very successful in reusing the answer therein in my case.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ \\
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \\
$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$ \\
$ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$ \\
$a\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\varkappa\lambda\mu\nu\xi o\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi\chi\psi\omega$ \\
$\Gamma\Delta\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega$ \\
$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\[
  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k) \cdot \text{Res}(f;a_k).
\]
\[
G(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-j\omega t} dt
\]
And this is nonmath text.

\end{document}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: The “canonical” question is [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The case `\int` is trivial, because there is an option `cmintegrals` for package `newtxmath`. In the other cases, the symbol fonts are overwritten by `newtxmath`. Therefore the example again defines them with a different name (`CM` appended):

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}

%% \sum
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsCM}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\let\txsum\sum
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{largesymbolsCM}{"50}

%% \infty
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsCM}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsCM}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\let\txinfty\infty
\DeclareMathSymbol{\infty}{\mathord}{symbolsCM}{"31}

%% \partial, \pi
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersCM}{OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersCM}{bold}{OML}{cmm} {b}{it}
\let\txpartial\partial
\DeclareMathSymbol{\partial}{\mathord}{lettersCM}{"40}
\let\txpi\pi
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{lettersCM}{"19}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \text{CM} &= \text{TX} \\
  \int \\
  \sum &= \txsum \\
  \infty &= \txinfty \\
  \partial &= \txpartial \\
  \pi &= \txpi
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Works very fine @Heiko Oberdiek, but please I need more clarification about the commands `\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsCM}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}` 
`\SetSymbolFont{symbolsCM}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}`. How do I know the parameters and names associated with a specific symbol. Forgive my shallow knowledge in this regard.

Comment: @AboAmmar A starting point is [LaTeX's font guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fntguide.pdf). In this case I have copied the lines from `fontmath.ltx` (part of the LaTeX kernel) with the a small change of the name (e.g. `symbolsCM` instead of `symbols`).

Comment: That helps so much. Thanks @Heiko Oberdiek. Although I read these information before, application is most important.

Comment: Do you know where I can look up the code for any other simbol? for instance where 50 is the code for \sum.

Comment: @N.Pullbacki In general, it depends on the used fonts and font packages. Here, the CM symbols can be taken from the definitions in `tds:tex/latex/base/fontmath.ltx`, e.g.: `\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"50}`.