# How to fatten (,), {,} and $\vee$ in math mode?

Tags: fonts, symbols

In order to distinguish between object language and meta language I want a rather visible difference between the signs mentioned in the title as used in the object language and as used in the formal meta language. How do I best achieve this?

I am not satisfied with the minor difference between $\boldsymbol{{}()\vee} and ${}()\vee$.

Perhaps there are some related symbols in http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf that I could use?

Comment: Maybe changing the font: `\mathtt{}`?

Comment: @Sigur That does not cut it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. Try to clarify your question.

Comment: Could you add an image or a minimal example of what exactly should be fat? bold font in math mode would be `\mathbf{}` or `\boldsymbol{}`

Comment: @MaxNoe See my edit.

Comment: @Sigur Try to clarify your reading.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal, so what you want is to change the math font locally.

Comment: I see your point, for me there is actually no difference between the `\mathbf{\vee}` and `\vee`, same for the brackets and parentheses.

Comment: @Sigur I do not understand how to change the math font locally.

Comment: Perhaps there are some alternative related symbols in http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal, related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200910/14757

Comment: Fatten could mean "bolden", it could mean "widen" or it could mean "bolden and widen".  Which do you seek?

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes As stated in my question I was seeking visible difference. As I have indicated an acceptance of an answer, how would you enlighten?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your follow-up question.  "Enlighten" could mean "make the font lighter" or it could mean to "explain my answer".  To the latter point,  in my answer, I chose the approach of using "embolden" as the primary means of providing a visible difference.  A the end of my answer, I added a little bit of "widen" to the "embolden" as a means to further differentiate the glyphs from their original appearance.  If you wanted the appearance to be "lighter" rather than "heavier", one might rely on either a narrowing of the glyph perhaps with a gray, rather than black color.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes I was just being fastidious. Sorry! I just now realized that you originated the answer I accepted! So I interpreted your first comment here as one that did not take your answer below into account.

I am very satisfied with your answer, and use the approach you kindly offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I introduce `\fat` that emboldens the argument with a multi-offset-overlay.  While it can be invoked in text mode or math mode, its argument is processed in math mode (unless delimited by `$` which will process it in text mode).  Importantly, the current math style is preserved.  For things like `\vee`, it is easier to define `\fvee` in terms of `\fat` and `\vee`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\fat[1]{\ThisStyle{\ooalign{%
  \kern.46pt$\SavedStyle#1$\cr\kern.33pt$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
  \kern.2pt$\SavedStyle#1$\cr$\SavedStyle#1$}}}
\def\fvee{\mathbin{\fat{\vee}}}
\begin{document}
$\{(xyz\vee abc)\} \scriptscriptstyle 
 \{(xyz\vee abc)\}$

$\fat\{\fat(xyz\fvee abc\fat)\fat\} \scriptscriptstyle 
 \fat\{\fat(xyz\fvee abc\fat)\fat\}$

\fat aa\fat{$a$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really wanted to enhance the effect, you could add a small horizontal stretch to the result (in this case 20%):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\fat[1]{\ThisStyle{\hstretch{1.2}{\ooalign{%
  \kern.46pt$\SavedStyle#1$\cr\kern.33pt$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
  \kern.2pt$\SavedStyle#1$\cr$\SavedStyle#1$}}}}
\def\fvee{\mathbin{\fat{\vee}}}
\begin{document}
$\{(xyz\vee abc)\} \scriptscriptstyle 
 \{(xyz\vee abc)\}$

$\fat\{\fat(xyz\fvee abc\fat)\fat\} \scriptscriptstyle 
 \fat\{\fat(xyz\fvee abc\fat)\fat\}$

\fat aa\fat{$a$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on package `pdfrender` to additionally stroke the symbols with a line width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for environment "gather*"
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\newcommand*{\fatten}[1][.4pt]{%
  \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    LineWidth={\dimexpr(#1)\relax},
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  (a \vee b) = \{a \vee b\}
\\
  \fatten{(} a \fatten{\vee} b \fatten{)} =
  \fatten{\{} a \fatten{\vee} b \fatten{\}}
\\
  \fatten[1pt]{(} a \fatten[1pt]{\vee} b \fatten[1pt]{)} =
  \fatten[1pt]{\{} a \fatten[1pt]{\vee} b \fatten[1pt]{\}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Caution:**

- The increased stroke width does *not* contribute to the width of the symbol.
  A macro can compensate this:

  ```
  \newcommand*{\fatvee}[1][1pt]{%
    \mathbin{%
      \kern.5\dimexpr(#1)\relax
      \fatten[{#1}]{\vee}%
      \kern.5\dimexpr(#1)\relax
    }%
  }
  ```

Full example with width compensation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for environment "gather*"
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\newcommand*{\fatten}[1][.4pt]{%
  \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    LineWidth={\dimexpr(#1)\relax},
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\fatdef}[4][1pt]{%
  % #1: optional stroke width
  % #2: new macro for fattened symbol
  % #3: math atom type (\mathbin, \mathrel, ...)
  % #4: symbol
  \newcommand*{#2}{%
    #3{%
      \kern.5\dimexpr(#1)\relax
      \fatten[{#1}]{#4}%
      \kern.5\dimexpr(#1)\relax
    }%
  }%
}
\fatdef\fatvee\mathbin\vee
\fatdef\fatlparen\mathopen(
\fatdef\fatrparen\mathclose)
\fatdef\fatlbrace\mathopen\{
\fatdef\fatrbrace\mathclose\}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  (a \vee b) = \{a \vee b\}
\\
  \fatlparen a \fatvee b \fatrparen =
  \fatlbrace a \fatvee b \fatrbrace
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with width compensation]

`\left` and `\right` can be supported by a macro that resets the rendering mode for the formula inside the fences:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for environment "gather*"
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\newcommand*{\fatten}[1][.4pt]{%
  \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    LineWidth={\dimexpr(#1)\relax},
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\fatdef}[4][1pt]{%
  % #1: optional stroke width
  % #2: new macro for fattened symbol
  % #3: math atom type (\mathbin, \mathrel, ...)
  % #4: symbol
  \newcommand*{#2}{%
    #3{%
      \kern.5\dimexpr(#1)\relax
      \fatten[{#1}]{#4}%
      \kern.5\dimexpr(#1)\relax
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\fatleftrightdef}[4][1pt]{%
  % #1: optional stroke width
  % #2: new macro name
  % #3: left fence
  % #4: right fence
  \newcommand*{#2}[1]{%
    \kern.5\dimexpr(#1)\relax
    \fatten[{#1}]{%
      \left#3%
      \kern.5\dimexpr(#1)\relax
      \textpdfrender{TextRenderingMode=Fill}{##1}%
      \kern.5\dimexpr(#1)\relax
      \right#4%
    }%
    \kern.5\dimexpr(#1)\relax
  }%
}
\fatdef\fatvee\mathbin\vee
\fatleftrightdef\fatleftrightparens()
\fatleftrightdef\fatleftrightbraces\{\}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \left( \frac{a}{a} \vee \frac{b}{b} \right) =
  \left\{ \frac{a}{a} \vee \frac{b}{b} \right\}
\\
  \fatleftrightparens{ \frac{a}{a} \fatvee \frac{b}{b} } =
  \fatleftrightbraces{ \frac{a}{a} \fatvee \frac{b}{b} }
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with \left and \right]