# Making Brackets more curvy in newtxmath

Tags: newtxmath

This is how the brackets look in the normal cmmodern math mode [image]

And the below image is using the "newtxmath package" [image]

So as one can see the brackets appear much better in the normal cm modern mode. Is there anyway by which I can make the brackets more curvy in the "newtxmath" mode??

Comment: "much better" is quite subjective, I fear. Clearly, the font designer liked those brackets better... Please give us an MWE from your both screen shots in order to make it easier for us. Note that this is most probably a duplicate to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200910

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Sure thanks. I have given the screenshot of the brackets. Isn't that ok? It would be nice if the brackets can me made as in the cm modern mode

Comment: No, we can not work with a screen shot. You just repeated your question but did not react on my comment. Have you read the post I linked to?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Yes. I did see it. But that post just addresses in chaning the summation symbol infinity symbol etc. It doesn't address changing the brackets. and what does MWE mean??

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like better the more slender parentheses, but it's not difficult to persuade LaTeX into using the CM ones.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

% Define the usual CM extension font
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
% Redeclare the parentheses to use CM for larger sizes
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen} {operators}{"28}{CMlargesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"29}{CMlargesymbols}{"01}

% a better command than \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)
\newcommand{\jacobi}[2]{\genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\[
\jacobi{5}{103}\cdot\jacobi{103}{5}=
(-1)^{\frac{103-1}{2}\cdot\frac{5-1}{2}}=1
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would I make LaTeX to use the CM version of the smallest size parentheses as well?