# Replacing all curly braces in a font (not just the large ones)

Tags: symbols, braces, math-fonts, kpfonts

I find the curly braces from kpfonts difficult to distinguish from other brace-like symbols and would like to replace all math instances of `\{` and `\}` (so `\lbrace` and `\rbrace`) with curlier braces from another font. For now CM will do but I'm open to other suggestions. Following the answers in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261870/208544) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79657/208544) I've succeeded in doing this for the large versions, i.e. when `\{` is preceded by `\left` or `\big` and so on:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\DeclareSymbolFont{CMlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"66}{CMlargesymbols}{"08}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"67}{CMlargesymbols}{"09}

\begin{document}
$\{a\} \quad \big\{a\big\}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The regular-sized braces are still from kpfonts. I thought perhaps `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` are declared twice, once for the regular case and another for `largesymbols`, but in [`source2e`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf) they are declared only for the `largesymbols` case.

A glance at, for example, `newtxmath.sty` makes it seem like changing the font for regular-sized `\lbrace`/`\rbrace` is done implicitly, not explicitly (its only declaration is for the large size; `kpfonts.sty` makes no declarations for them which confuses me further).

How do I change the font for the regular-size case as well?

P.S. I know the font designer made the braces as they are for a reason. This is just for personal use to increase readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to change the braces at normal size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\DeclareSymbolFont{CMsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n} % <---
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{CMsymbols}{"66}{CMlargesymbols}{"08} % <---
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}{\mathopen}{CMsymbols}{"67}{CMlargesymbols}{"09} % <---


\begin{document}

$\{a\} \quad \bigl\{a\bigr\}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `\big` with delimiters; use `\bigl` and `\bigr` for opening and closing respectively.