# Change symbol of partial derivate

Tags: symbols

I want the symbol of partial derivate  exactly like this[image]

Because I don´t like the original symbol of partial derivate
[image]

Comment: Almost exact duplicate: [Replace a few math symbols in the newtxmath font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200910/replace-a-few-math-symbols-in-the-newtxmath-font)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The two screenshots show two very different math fonts: Times Roman Math in the upper, Computer Modern Math in the lower. Do you want to change the entire math font or just the symbol for `\partial`?

Comment: More general duplicate: [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font)