# Change some symbols in newtxmath

Tags: symbols, newtxmath

I use newtxmath and I don't like these symbols

[image]

I like the symbols of Computer Modern, how can I change them?

Comment: Maybe someone here knows the answer immediately. Otherwise, it might help if you add the code for the first line (the one that you don''t like).

Comment: Please check the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200910/replace-a-few-math-symbols-in-the-newtxmath-font) to a similar question.